# Firefox returning incorrect JSON using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a post to an API endpoint. It seems to work in safari and chrome even ie. But firefox seems to want to add a double quote to the beginning and end of the json string. I dont know that this is a huge issue to most of the community but I am under deadline and this is the only thing keeping me from hitting my target.

```
    console.log(JSON.stringify($('FooObject').serializeObject()));
```

This returns

```
    "{"key":"value"}"
```

I need

```
    {"key":"value"}
```

Any suggestions? I have trolled the net for about 3 hours and no dice.

Please be nice I do not do js often, more than often I do networking and security this is a edge case that I need tackled.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not adding anything. It's just a console display. The quotes aren't actually there. Don't rely merely on a console output to determine if you have a bug or not.

Comment: To be certain, add `[0] === "{"` to the end of your `.stringify()` call. If it's `true`, then the first character is a `{`,  not a `"`. `console.log(JSON.stringify($('FooObject').serializeObject())[0] === "{");`

Comment: I did test that and it did come back true. It works now. It was an API error. Thanks for your help @lye fish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the double quotes display in the Firefox console- then quotes are just to signify that it's a string.

Comment: I understand but that is not allowing it to save it. Even JSON Lint considers it malformed json.

Comment: I did test that and it did come back true. It works now. It was an API error. Thanks for your help @wonderheart